# Unreadable captcha

Tags: support, captcha

I wanted to add my answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174287/how-do-i-convert-an-mp4-to-an-mp3) post but I keep on being told to enter the text on a captcha. The problem is that the captcha text is bearly readable and no success after about five tries.

I tried logging out and in again with no luck. How can I tell them am human or use a more readable captcha? See below...even the captcha sound doesn't help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think there is an option to update the captcha if you cant read it. Like a recycle symbol.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Yeah but I have tried like ten times now all telling me "Oops! Those aren't the correct words"

Comment: Just curious but did you try another browse.

Comment: Chromium worked. No captcha, maybe I needed to clear my firefox cache first.